# Can't connect to local area server with asp.net page on Android

Tags: android, local, network-protocols, httpurlconnection

I'm new here and I wish I won't make any bloomer :)

I'm developing some android app and have stucked in connecting to other computer, where I've installed ASP.net page. I can't emulate it due to problems with connecting to host.

The code that I'm using:

```
public class SPCChartViewerActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String strData = urlData("http://[server]/SPCOnline/SQLQuery.aspx?query=SELECT%20NAME%20FROM%20SPC_CHARTS");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(strData);
}

private String urlData(String urlString){
    URLConnection urlConnection = null;
    URL url = null;
    String string = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while((string = reader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuffer.append(string + "\n");
        }
        inputStream.close(); 
        string = stringBuffer.toString();
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return string;
}
```

}

In tag [server] I've put:

- that computer's name: `http://miltstx155srv01/SPCOnline/SQLQuery.aspx?query=SELECT%20NAME%20FROM%20SPC_CHARTS`
  In this case I receive java.net:UnknownHostException
- that computer's IP: `http://10.72.152.163/SPCOnline/SQLQuery.aspx?query=SELECT%20NAME%20FROM%20SPC_CHARTS`
  In this case I receive java.net:FileNotFoundException
- If I ommit the "http://" I receive java.net:Protocol Not Found

Ok, maybe something with my company's DNS. So I've put this page on my computer, which is also running AVD emulator. So the url is now: `http://10.0.2.2/SPCOnline/SQLQuery.aspx?query=SELECT%20NAME%20FROM%20SPC_CHARTS` - but still java.net:UnknownHostException.

Of course clause **uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"** is added to manifest.

Still, every example written upper works fine with webbrowser (of course except 10.0.2.2 - but changing it to localhost makes it work).

No idea, I've spent whole day testing it. Can anyone help?